# Accessing openvpn from script without storing password on file

Tags: shell-script, openvpn

```
sudo openvpn  --config ubuntu.ovpn --auth-user-pass file
```

I know this command. Is there any other way to give password without using file.
For suppose in wget I can use --http-user --http-password flags for authentication. I wrote a shell script which needs authentication  multiple times, so my plan is to read username and password just one time from the user, store it on normal variables, and use the same username and password for multiple applications in which openvpn is one but it is strict no to store username and password in files. Are there any similar flags like what we have in wget to authenticate in openvpn

Comment: Yes, entering it by hand.

Answer (score 0):

There are several different ways to set up authentication in OpenVPN. This provides a lot of flexibility. Here is a list of some of the options available to you:

1. You can use username/password authentication with and without certificate authentication to authenticate a user

   - Username and password can be embedded in an authentication file
   - Username and password can be entered on demand
2. You can use a shared secret to authenticate the client and server
3. You *may* be able to use certificate-based authentication without username/password to authenticate a user (I haven't tried this myself).

You haven't provided sufficient detail to offer a possible solution implementation for your situation so I shall stop at this list.